# datastore_v3.Put() was explicitly cancelled

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I am Using Hibernate + google-Cloud-SQL in my project

its working fine but it slow some time and when we make more calls it give me following Exception :-

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call datastore_v3.Put() was explicitly cancelled.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$5.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:385)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$5.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:382)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$CumulativeAggregateFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:145)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:72)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:33)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:31)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:94)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore.saveSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:94)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager$AppEngineSession.save(SessionManager.java:156)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:41)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
```

Comment: This is a datastore error, are you sure you are effectively using CloudSQL?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you've reached the time limit for the servlet request or Task, and you're not still able to use Google Services like persistence(datastore, memcache, cloud sql, storage) and the others.